# .sln or .csproj which one do I turn into a .wsp?

Tags: solution-package

I am wanting to create a `wsp` from my solution but I am wondering which one I turn into the `wsp`, the `.sln` or the `.csproj`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open solution in **Visual Studio**.

**Right click** on the solution and **deploy** or **build** the solution.

[image]

Now check your **solution configuration**

[image]

If your are in debug mode, then find your `.wsp` in the following folder

```
PathOfYourSolution\bin\Debug
```

If your are in release mode, then find your `.wsp` in the following folder

```
PathOfYourSolution\bin\Release
```

Answer (score 7):

You can have multiple SharePoint projects (.csproj) in the same Visual Studio solution (.sln). Each SharePoint project builds into a WSP (right-click on the **project** and select "Package" or "Publish" depending on your version of VS). "Package" (or "Publish") will first build the project and then create the .wsp.

A Visual Studio Solution (.sln) is not at all mapped to the SharePoint solution (.wsp) concept!

Answer (score 2):

You can't turn .sln into a WSP. A .csproj created using appropriate SharePoint project template is turned into a WSP when you choose to deploy.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find this video valuable. In it I describe what a Solution Package (WSP) is and how to create and deploy one. Although the video was recorded for SharePoint 2010, the material applies to SharePoint 2013 and 2016.

[SharePoint 2010 for ASP.NET Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=an1IkFzHpBk)